# Squaring the circle, compass-and-straightedge construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

I have to proof that is not possible with compass-and-straightedge to construct a square which has surface equal to a disk.

Let $M\subset \mathbb{C}$ with $\{0, 1\} \subset M$ and let $\cal{M}$ the set of numbers that can be constructed from $M$.

Let $ c(M) = \{ \overline{z} : z \in M \}$ and let $Q(M \cup c(M)):= \{ \cap \, K : K \, \ \text{subfield}, \, \,M \cup c(M) \subset K \}$.

I have some trouble to proof that the field-extension $Q(M \cup c(M)) \subset \cal{M}$ is algebraic (is the essential step in the squaring a circle problem).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to find this in any introductory book about Galois theory. Or just google it.

Comment: The essential thing is to show that from some starting field, a circle with coordinates and radius in that field meets a line through two points in that field in points that are quadratic over that field, and the same for the intersection of two such circles. Both of those are just straightforward calculations.

Comment: Well, it depends on the radius of the disk and whether you happen to have some convenient point at your disposal or not.